# Android Rounded Edges for backgrounds

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-ndk

I was wondering if anyone knew how to make rounded background edges for only certain corners.

For example, in the lock screen of Android 2.2 there were the two slidingDrawers to unlock the phone and take a picture or something.

The slidingDrawers had a rounded corner with an icon within it. Anyone know how to make the corners of a background rounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways in achieving that.

You could use a [9patch drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html), and I'm guessing that's what they used.

You can also use a [shape drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape), with proper corners.

Other than that, your question is too ambiguous. But this should provide enough for a good answer to your problem.

Comment: Hey David, Thanks a lot. I made a shape drawable and set that as my background for my image and it works pretty well. :)

Answer (score 2):

you can create a xml file inside the drawable folder with some code like this ,

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
      <corners android:radius="5px"/>
      <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp"          android:bottom="0dp" /> 
      </shape>
```

change the radius values for the amount of rounded edge you need. Apply this xml as the background of your textview or edittext or anything.

Comment: "<corners android:radius="5px"/>"
You should not use px. Use dp instead.
"<corners android:radius="5dp"/>"